# Select all records whose specific field is not NULL

Tags: java, mysql, select, prepared-statement, notnull

I have a `MySQL` table named `stars` and one of its fields is `id_num` with default value `NULL`. I want to select all the records where `id_num` ***is not*** `NULL` through a `PreparedStatement` in [java](/questions/tagged/java).

Right now I am trying this :

```
private final String idStarsSQL = "select * from `stars` where id_num is not ?";
...

preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(idStarsSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, NULL);
set = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

but it is not working.

Comment: You do not Need a prepared Statement here. use simply `select * from stars where id_num is not null`

Comment: @Jens  And how will I connect this string with the database? I mean, now I have `.executeQuery();` . What will I do after I declare this string?

Comment: `.executeQuery(idStarsSQL); `. Also you can use it with prepared Statement but without parameter

Comment: @Jens  aah so you mean that I should just erase the statement `preparedStatement.setString(1, NULL);`, right? And just write `NULL` in my string.

Comment: yes that's what i mean

Comment: @Jens thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private final String idStarsSQL = "select * from `stars` where id_num is not NULL";
```

you dont need a `PreparedStatement` for this.

From my point of view PreparedStatement should be used for  SQL statements that take parameters. The advantage of using SQL statements that take parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with different values each time you execute it.

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select username, age, nickname from user where nickname is not NULL");
    List<User> allUserNullNickname = new ArrayList<>();
    while(result.next()){
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(result.getString("username"));
        user.setAge(result.getInt("age"));
        allUserNullNickname.add(user);
    }
    System.out.println("All user without nickname:");
    allUserNullNickname.stream().forEach(user -> System.out.println("username: "+user.getUsername()+" Age: "+user.getAge()));
```

Comment: That's what I am saying... I do need a PreparedStatement, based on your answer. I got it, thanks a lot!!

Comment: OK now you changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Because null is a not a value, it more of a keyword in SQL, so you have to hard code it into your sql statement

```
private final String idStarsSQL = "select * from `stars` where id_num is not NULL";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
            connection.prepareStatement("select * from `stars` where id_num is not NULL");
ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (result.next()) {
    result.getString("attribute1");
    result.getString("attribute2");
}
```

You can learn more here about [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and about [ResulSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Answer (score 0):

The preparedStatement's primary feature is to  insert parameters into the SQL statement and in your case you dont need to do this because null is not a param so you can clearly  do :

```
PreparedStatement myRequest= 
            connection.prepareStatement("select * from `stars` where id_num is not NULL");
ResultSet myResult= preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```